# Open the nth app on the Dock

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, dock

In Windows, you can open the nth application on the taskbar by doing Windows key + n. How do you do this on a Mac (keyboard shortcut)?

Comment: There's no Mac equivalent that I know of. There are ways to launch an app by key command [using Automator/Applescript or 3rd party tools], but not based on position in the dock.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any shortcut without using a scripting tool but I use a simple, dirty hack.

I use the [Raycast](https://raycast.com) launcher (love it!). In its extension panel, I've created numbered hotkeys using the Option modifier key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) where the number corresponds to the position of the app in the dock. For example, <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>13</kbd> is for Finder, <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> for LaunchPad, <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> for Arc Browser, etc.

This generally works great except when I have to reorder the apps in the dock. For this reason, I don't change the order of the first 10 apps.

[image: Dock]

[image: Raycast settings]